# Can't create a group named "search"

Tags: gitlab

I need create a new group for our search project.
But "search" is a keyword of gitlab, how to fix this?
Does the only way is change a new group instead of "search"?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can call the [GitLab "New group" API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/groups.html#new-group), with a [`curl` call](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#basic-usage).

That would allow to create from command-line a new group, for which you can test the name "`search`".

But if the end-result would collide with a GitLab URL endpoint (`/search`), then it would make sense it is rejected. Test it out.